# WooCommerce checkout 'internal server error' fail to load ?wc-ajax=checkout

Tags: woocommerce

Our WooCommerce Site produces an error on Checkout. This was not fixed when I updated to the latest WC version. The only thing that changed between it working and the error is the version of WordPress... The error is in checkout after you submit your payment info (credit card, using Authorize.net) you get the message 'Internal Server Error'. The order does appear in the WC Orders section, a customer account is created, payment is also submitted (but marked as pending).  The Console shows a 500 error for ?wc-ajax=checkout

in debug the errors I get are:

```
Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in LayerSlider_Widget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use

__construct()

instead. in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/30/2845930/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3892

Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in SocialWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use

__construct()

instead. in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/30/2845930/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3892

Notice: The called constructor method for WP_Widget in ContactsWidget is deprecated since version 4.3.0! Use

__construct()

instead. in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/30/2845930/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3892

Strict Standards: Declaration of WC_Shipping_USPS::calculate_shipping() should be compatible with WC_Shipping_Method::calculate_shipping($package = Array) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/30/2845930/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-shipping-usps/includes/class-wc-shipping-usps.php on line 0

Strict Standards: Declaration of WC_Shipping_UPS::calculate_shipping() should be compatible with WC_Shipping_Method::calculate_shipping($package = Array) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/30/2845930/html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-shipping-ups/includes/class-wc-shipping-ups.php on line 0

Notice: Use of undefined constant outlet_primary_colour - assumed 'outlet_primary_colour' in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas08_data03/30/2845930/html/wp-content/themes/outlet/includes/theme_customize.php on line 1231
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved. Apparently, WooThemes own plugins got 'disconnected' and although I had updated the licenses and the plugins, they didn't 'connect' so the updates were not 'live'. I had to disconnect my WooThemes account and remove and reinstall the WooThemes Helper Plugin - once I did, I could reconnect the plugins and then they actually updated. This SOLVED the problem. The main issue for me were the UPS and USPS plugins which were not updated and thus not compatible with the latest WOO standard for Shipping Zones. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error could be caused by many things. Do you have access to your apache/php error logs?  That's the quickest way to figure it out in most cases.

Comment: I added the debug errors in my original post (can't add it to a comment). also note that I updated the following: emails are now good (after flushing cache) an account is created each time, and the payment also appears to be working/submitted. It's just that the page the user gets shows the error rather than an order confirmation page. I know my theme templates are out of date... but which one and what specifically would cause a 500 error?